# "Failed at step EXEC spawning" even with proper group permissions

Tags: security, permissions, groups, systemd

I'm setting up permissions for a basic web server, but having some difficulty with starting the server with systemd.

In my job description, I set the user and group to "foo", as follows:

```
[Service]

WorkingDirectiory=/home/otheruser/Website
ExecStart=/home/otheruser/Website/bin/site -Dhttp.port=7000

User=foo
Group=foo
```

I recursively changed the group for the `Website` directory to `foo`, and made sure to give group execution rights to the `site` binary. When I still had issues, I `chown`d the whole directory for `foo`. Here's what `ls -la` displays in the `bin` directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 foo foo  4096 Sep  5 16:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 foo foo  4096 Sep  5 18:07 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 foo foo  8502 Sep  5 16:13 site
```

Anyhow, I'm still getting this error when trying to start my systemd job:

```
foo.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/otheruser/Website/bin/site: Permission denied
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: With `Permission denied` errors not only the traditional UGO permissions in the executable (and the complete path leading there) can be an issue, also SELinux violations are often reported as such.

Comment: @HBruijn We can see from his question that SELinux is disabled.

Comment: @HBruijn How can you see that?

Comment: @Nathan: Michael is a better sharper than I am and noticed that the `ls` output did not show a trailing `.` after the UGO permissions `drwxr-xr-x` - GNU `ls` uses a `.` character to indicate a file with an SELinux
     security context, but no other alternate access method. A file with any other combination of alternate access methods is
     marked with a `+` character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After tinkering around some more, I ended up discovering that some directories higher up in the tree (namely `/home/otheruser`) wasn't allowing execution by `foo`. While the `Website` directory had correct permissions, the above directories didn't, which was causing the failure.