# Failed at step EXEC spawning... Permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, fedora, systemd, exec

I have read alot about this but still not sure why this is not working. as far as I know all dirs have the right permission and even with everything being 777 I still get permission denied when trying to run this program as a service. the program I am trying to run as a servoce is called xTeVe. I have tried runing it under all differient dirs, users, and nothing seems to work.

Heres the Unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=XTeVe For Plex
After=network.target network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/root/IPTV/xteve
user=root
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
StartLimitInterval=60s
StartLimitBurst=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I do know that this shouldnt be run as root but that was just the last user I tried

And when i try to start the service i get this:

```
14:20 xteve.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
14:02 xteve.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
14:02 xteve.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /root/IPTV/xteve: Permission denied
14:02 xteve.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
14:02 Started XTeVe For Plex.
```

And this is the file permissions:

```
[root@skynet IPTV]# ls -la
total 12084
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root       19 Mar  6 13:58 .
dr-xr-x---. 5 root root      175 Mar  6 13:58 ..
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 12370316 Mar  6 13:58 xteve
```

Result of `file`:

```
[root@skynet IPTV]# file xteve
xteve: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, Go BuildID=lt4S9w02Ylf_MXsFeRkj/jdmwTx5YSsQSDaa6tfuz/vCzfZlCyl5qUEBD7IuD0/AEI-OmWm1iNuziWA7R0P, with debug_info, not stripped
```

Output of `cat audit.log | grep xteve`:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1551898814.098:1342): avc:  denied  { execute } for pid=11002 comm="(xteve)" name="xteve" dev="dm-0" ino=30958 scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
type=SERVICE_STOP msg=audit(1551898814.100:1343): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=xteve comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'UID="root" AUID="unset"
type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1551898814.420:1344): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=xteve comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'UID="root" AUID="unset"
type=SERVICE_STOP msg=audit(1551898814.420:1345): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=xteve comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'UID="root" AUID="unset"
type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1551898966.689:1385): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=xteve comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=?res=success'UID="root" AUID="unset"
```

Things I have tried but didnt work:

[systemd Failed at step EXEC spawning script: Permission denied](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209097/systemd-failed-at-step-exec-spawning-script-permission-denied)

[systemd custom service: Failed at step EXEC spawning … Permission denied](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408840/systemd-custom-service-failed-at-step-exec-spawning-permission-denied?rq=1)

[“Failed at step EXEC spawning” even with proper group permissions](https://serverfault.com/questions/801195/failed-at-step-exec-spawning-even-with-proper-group-permissions)

Comment: Check the audit log.

Comment: Could you add the result of "file xteve" ?

Comment: @Dom when you mean resualt of file xteve, you mean if i run it manually with the command line?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Where would i find that?

Comment: @Stone Monarch : Yes, open a terminal, and run "file xteve". Type enter. The result must be copy/paste here

Comment: @Dom Added it to the original question too

[root@skynet IPTV]# file xteve                                                                                                                                                                 
xteve: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, Go BuildID=lt4S9w02Ylf_MXsFeRkj/jdmwTx5YSsQSDaa6tfuz/vCzfZlCyl5qUEBD7IuD0/AEI-OmWm1iNuziWA7R0P, with debug_info,
 not stripped

Comment: It's in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`. You will get new entries each time you try to start the service. Please try to start the service again and then copy and paste the newly added entries.

Comment: And your Linux is a 64 bits or a 32 bits ? execute "uname -m"

Comment: @MichaelHampton audit log now in question

Comment: @Dom 64bit `x86_64`

Comment: @Dom Thank you very much for your help Michael Hampton has resolved the issue. But much appreciated for your efforts

Answer (score 55, accepted):

SELinux prevents you from running a system service where the binary is in a user's home directory, or in your case, the root user's home directory.

To fix the problem, copy the binary to a proper directory such as `/usr/local/bin` and call it from there.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked. My friend and I have been loosing our minds for a week over this

Comment: Note if you move service files from a home directory to a "proper directory", their SELinux context remains "home". You can reset this by running `sudo restorecon -rv /path/to/moved/directory`

Comment: If someone wants solve this problem by changing the SELinux settings, run this command to change "Enforcing" to "Permissive":  setenforce 0

Answer (score 0):

I ran in that issue as well. In my case, though, the script I use to start my service is under `/usr/bin/...`, so clearly not inside a user directory (`/home/<name>/...` or `/root/...`).

However, I wanted to have the `WorkingDirectory=/home/...` defined with the user home directory. That is what caused issue. The CHDIR failed for that service in the same way you mentioned above.

So instead I create a system user with a `<package>.sysuser` file and corresponding `--with sysuser` in the `debian/rules` file.

```
%:
    dh $@ --parallel --with sysuser
```

The `<package>.sysuser` file looks like this:

```
# Create a user "<Name>" and corresponding group "<Name>"
# and create a home directory (a.k.a. /var/lib/<Name>)
#
# see: man dh_sysuser
#
# Name            Options
<user-name>       home
```

where `<user-name>` is my top secret user name. You'll have to install the `dh_sysuser` extension if you haven't already.

```
sudo apt-get install dh-sysuser
```

You may also need that as a dependency in your `debian/control` file:

```
Build-Depends: dh-sysuser, ...
```

Now my system user has a home folder under `/var/lib/<user-name>/...` and starting a service from there works as expected, no more CHDIR errors.